# Currency conversion in CMS page

Tags: magento2, cms, currency

I need to put some prices into a CMS page. How can I insert and display them accordingly to the currency selected?

Comment: On which section you want to price conversation?.Provide more infomation.

Comment: @AmitBera What do you mean by section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, try to add the below code in theme .phtml file and add that phtml file in the cms page.

theme/test.phtml

```
$this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(10.5, true, false);
```

CMS Page content

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="theme/test.phtml"}}
```

I hope this will help you. Please let me know if this will not work, I have not tested this from my end.

Thanks.

Comment: It says `Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'theme/test.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'`.

Comment: I solved adding it in a custom module under `view/frontend/templates` path. It seems to work well. Is there any issues using Varnish cache?

Comment: Maybe, It will create issues in varnish. Please check and let me know.
Apart from this, please accept this as the correct answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give different delivery price depend on store view.

As if you have a store with currency $ and the name of the store is us.. Then you need to change the store to US. Then add a different price for that store.